# how to make the carousel Image slider from database in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, carousel

Suppose a product has multiple images, now in the product's details page, I want to display all those images as carousel slider. Now how can I implement this in asp.net mvc. Please help me out!!
I have this set of codes -

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Images)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.ImgCount;)
                        {
                            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@i"></li>

                                </ol>

                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner">


                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="~/img/@item.Image" alt="@Model.Name" style="width:100%;">
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            i++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

This is showing me all the images one by one...
Please help me out in this.. I'm new to MVC...

Comment: You need some client slide  carousel slider plugins . If it works with a static HTML page, you can make it work with mvc, by generating similar HTML markup

Comment: I tried using bootstrap carousel, it's working in static HTML, but while implementing in this, it's not working!!

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Check your browser console and see whether you have any errors. Also are you sure you generated the correct HTML markup ? Can you share a jsfiddle where your static HTML is not working ? ( MVC generates pure HTML. So it should also work)

Comment: Compare the HTML generated by your view code with your working static HTML version

Comment: Here, I'm using this code example, which is working in HTML, bot in MVC - 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Comment: Yeah, I got it, but how do I make one item as active, it's inside the for loop.

Comment: Take a look at the answer i posted. That has the code to handle it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code is generating the entire markup including the containers inside the loop. That means, if your collection has 5 items, it will generate the full HTML markup (including the containers) 5 times.

All you need to render dynamically with the loop is the div with class `carousel-item` and it's inner content. You also need to make sure you are setting the `active` css class to **only one slide**. ( *If you set more than one slide with that css class, all will be visibl*e)

The below code should work

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @{
            var first = true;
        }
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Images)
        {
            <div class="carousel-item @(first?Html.Raw("active"):Html.Raw(""))">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="@item.Image" alt="@item.Name">
            </div>
            first = false;
        }
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
                                     data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
                                     data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, #Shyju, It worked! I appreciate your help :)